Installing application manually on offline Fedora
I'm running a Fedora VM on a Fedora host, and I'm trying to install emacs.  Due to reasons, I can't access the internet from the VM.  I can rsync between the host and the VM, but yum/apt/etc is a black box to me, so I'm not sure if there's anything I need to copy over aside from /bin/emacs or /usr/bin/emacs (Also not sure of the difference there?)

If you can access the guest from the host or the host from the guest, you could easily set up the host as a proxy (ssh remote forwarding + squid or something with the former, ssh dynamic forwarding as a socks proxy in the latter)

You can't just copy over a binary and expect it to work. You'd be missing 99% of emacs if you did that, and all the dependencies it has. You will need to actually do the same things that happen as on a system with internet connection when you dnf install emacs.
frankly, the easiest way would be to "re-provision the VM" (i.e., set it up from scratch, with internet acces) and install emacs while doing that.
Obviously, that's not always desirable. In case you wonder how to manage that: you can use kickstart files to automate the complete fedora installation (in a VM, you usually don't want to do anything fancy with partitioning and whatnot,
So, the alternative (completely ignoring whether this is about dnf, or apt, or nuget, or anaconda or pip or any other package manager) to that would be to

download the current information on available packages and how they depend on each other on an internet-connected machine,
move that info to the offline machine,
run dnf on the offline machine to now figure out which currently available packages would need to get installed
move that information to an internet-connected machine (can be the host, another VM),
download these packages there,
move them back to the offline machine and
install them.

Note that 1. is rather important, because installing a fresh emacs package might require a dependency in a version newer than what is already available on the machine. You can also just download all the potentially used packages – but that's a full Fedora installation, and I don't know whether that's worth it. An alternative would be to become your own fedora mirror, but that's going to download all fedora packages, just so you can install a few. You'd need to have a lot of storage space, time, and might also want to consider the effect that has on mirror bandwidth available to users that only download what they need.
What I'd probably do instead is either:

install emacs into an e.g. Fedora (podman) container, get container image, copy into VM, run container in VM
install emacs using flatpak, use flatpak create-usb to get the emacs flatpak and all its dependencies into something that can be moved into the VM.

In both cases, you need some specific software (podman or flatpak) to be available in the VM.
Or, I'd circumvent the need for emacs in the VM completely, and just use the remote access capabilities of emacs (TRAMP, terrible name) to access the files you might want to edit from a different VM or the host machine via network. That requires network access of some sorts.

Thank you for your detailed answer!  This may be useful in the future.  Unfortunately, since posting, I've been told the proffered solution is to develop on the host machine, and just use the VM for testing.
